Different bibliographies for same citations
Problem: Some citations have alternative presentation (typically original language version). Therefore, there should be two bibliographies. The second bibliography should include all sources, but for sources with alternative data use bibentry with a citation key *:alt.
My solution: two bib files with duplicate sources that have no alternative bibentry. See an example where ref2 has two different titles.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ref1,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
@book{ref2,
 author = {Schlichting, H.},
 pages = {483},
 publisher = {G. Braun},
 title = {Boundary layer theory},
 year = {1951}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_alt.bib}
@book{ref1:alt,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
@book{ref2:alt,
 author = {Schlichting, H.},
 pages = {483},
 publisher = {G. Braun},
 title = {Original title: Grenzschicht-Theorie},
 year = {1951}
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bibnocite}[1]{%
    \blx@xsanitizeafter{\forcsvlist\bibnocite@do}{#1}}
\newcommand*{\bibnocite@do}[1]{%
    \nocite{#1:alt}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\bblcite}[1]{\cite{#1}\bibnocite{#1}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname_alt.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{ % стираем ключевые слова
            \step[fieldsource=keywords]
            \step[fieldset=keywords,null]
        }
        \map[overwrite]{
            \perdatasource{\jobname.bib}
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,bibliography}, append]
        }
        \map[overwrite]{
            \perdatasource{\jobname_alt.bib}
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,bibliography-alt}, append]
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
Books \bblcite{ref1,ref2}

\printbibliography[title=References, keyword={bibliography}, resetnumbers]

\printbibliography[title=References-alt, keyword={bibliography-alt}, resetnumbers]

\end{document}

Here it is result

I'm looking for a solution on how to get the same result, but using a single bib file and no duplicates for reference that have no alternative.

Welcome! Is the content of the two bibliographies imposed by some requirement? It seems a bit confusing to me because you effectively have labels pointing to two different places. I guess that's why you don't want to use the Biblatex apparatus for handling such cases (origlanguage, origtitle etc.)?

@cfr, yes, it is imposed. Sometimes whole alternative reference is different (not just the title).

Well, indeed. Biblatex is setup for the whole reference being different. That's not an issue. When you say 'no duplicates', do you mean in the input only? Or do you mean in the output, too? Does this approach have a name? Which discipline/institution needs this? That might make it easier to search for solutions. How do other people manage this?

@cfr, Scopus requires journals all references are in Roman script and preferably in English. So non-English language papers are commonly published with two bibliographies. I've shown the solution that other people found. It works well but it is not as convenient as could be. First of all, how to avoid repetition in ref1:alt (it's the same as ref1). Second, it would be nice to have all  entries in one bib file.

I can think of a way to avoid duplicating entries, but that would depend on having the two .bib files. Otherwise, maybe you could markup the entries using the standard syntax (origlocation, origdate etc.) and then use mapping to switch them in. But you'd have to have a style which didn't use those fields ordinarily ....

I'm not sure how to switch. Could you please demonstrate with my example above?
